# How to make a set backed by a map?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, set

There is a method in the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class.

`Set<E> Collections.newSetFromMap(<backing map>)`

What does it mean by *the backing map* and *the set backed by a map*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps it would be illuminating to look at the implementation:

```
private static class SetFromMap<E> extends AbstractSet<E>
    implements Set<E>, Serializable
{
    private final Map<E, Boolean> m;  // The backing map
    private transient Set<E> s;       // Its keySet

    SetFromMap(Map<E, Boolean> map) {
        if (!map.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Map is non-empty");
        m = map;
        s = map.keySet();
    }

    public void clear()               {        m.clear(); }
    public int size()                 { return m.size(); }
    public boolean isEmpty()          { return m.isEmpty(); }
    public boolean contains(Object o) { return m.containsKey(o); }
    public boolean remove(Object o)   { return m.remove(o) != null; }
    public boolean add(E e) { return m.put(e, Boolean.TRUE) == null; }
    public Iterator<E> iterator()     { return s.iterator(); }
    public Object[] toArray()         { return s.toArray(); }
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)     { return s.toArray(a); }
    public String toString()          { return s.toString(); }
    public int hashCode()             { return s.hashCode(); }
    public boolean equals(Object o)   { return o == this || s.equals(o); }
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {return s.containsAll(c);}
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c)   {return s.removeAll(c);}
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c)   {return s.retainAll(c);}
    // addAll is the only inherited implementation

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2454657854757543876L;

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        stream.defaultReadObject();
        s = m.keySet();
    }
}
```

**Edit - added explanation:**

The map that you provide is used as the `m` field in this object.

When you add an element `e` to the set, it adds an entry `e -> true` to the map.

```
public boolean add(E e) { return m.put(e, Boolean.TRUE) == null; }
```

So this class turns your `Map` into an object that behaves like a `Set` by simply ignoring the values that things are mapped to, and just using the keys.

Comment: My main question is backing set and map.. What do you mean by them and a simple example would be useful..

Comment: What is this. I am more interested in the values() set than the keyset.

Answer (score 5):

I just made an example code for you

```
HashMap<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

Set<String> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(map);

System.out.println(set);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    map.put("" + i, i % 2 == 0);

System.out.println(map);

System.out.println(set);
```

and the output

```
[]
{3=false, 2=true, 1=false, 0=true, 7=false, 6=true, 5=false, 4=true, 9=false, 8=true}
[3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8]
```

Comment: From the Javadoc: There is no need to use this method on a Map implementation that already has a corresponding Set implementation (such as HashMap or TreeMap).

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, [Collections.newSetFromMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap%28java.util.Map%29) uses the provided `Map<E>` implementation to store the `Set<E>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

The Set internally uses Map to store the values. Here the backing map refers to the set map which is internally used by the set.
For more information.
http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/inside-set.php